# DirectShow, specifically Rate Matching, time stamps and the DirectSound Audio Renderer

Tags: audio, time, directshow, renderer, rate

Can anyone give me a concise explanation of how and why DirectShow DirectSound Audio Renderer will adjust the rate when I have my custom capture filter that does not expose a clock?

I cannot make any sense of it at all. When audio starts, I assign a rtStart of zero plus the duration of the sample (numbytes / m_wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec). Then the next sample has a start time of the end of the previous sample, and so on....

Some time later, the capture filter senses Directshow is consuming samples too rapidly, and tries to set a timestamp of some time in the future, which the audio renderer completely ignores. I can, as a test, suddenly tell a sample it must not be rendered until 20 secs in the future (StreamTime() + UNITS), and again the renderer just ignores it. However, the Null Audio Renderer does what it is told, and the whole graph freezes for 20 seconds, which is the expected behaviour.

In a nutshell, then, I want the audio renderer to use either my capture clock (or its own, or the graph's, I dont care) but I do need it to obey the time stamps I'm sending to it. What I need it to do is squish or stretch samples, ever so subtly, to make up for the difference in the rates between DSound and the oncoming stream (whose rate I cannot control).

Answer (score 1):

MSDN explains the technology here: [Live Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I suppose you are aware of this documentation topic.

Rate matching takes place when your source is live, otherwise audio renderer does not need to bother and it expects the source to keep input queue pre-loaded with data, so that data is consumed at the rate it is needed.

It seems that your filter is capturing in real time (capture filter and then you mention you don't control the rate of data you obtain externally). So you need to make sure your capture filter is recognized as live source and then you choose the clock for playback, and overall the mode of operation. I suppose you want the behavior described hear `AM_PUSHSOURCECAPS_PRIVATE_CLOCK`:

> the source filter is using a private clock to generate time stamps. In this case, the audio renderer matches rates against the time stamps.

This is what you write about above:

- you time stamp according to external source
- playback is using audio device clock
- audio renderer does rate matching to match the rates

To see how exactly rate matching takes place, you need to open audio renderer property pages, Advanced page:

[image: Advanced Property Page]

Data under Slaving Info will show the rate matching details (48000/48300 matching in my example). The data is also available programmatically via [`IAMAudioRendererStats::GetStatParam`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hello Roman -- I am indeed doing the AM_PUSHSOURCECAPS_PRIVATE_CLOCK thing and exposing the clock via QI. In the renderer stats, I observe that the slaving info says "Live Timestamps" and just sits at (what I presume is max. speed for a 44100 sr: 44713. So the renderer thinks the rate is too fast, and I don't know why!

Comment: What I did not understand is what is the effect you are observing. Rate matching - which you presumably take as incorrect - does it end up in playback buffer underrun? overrun? The check of scheduling a sample to 20 seconds in future is understandable: when rate matching is enabled and it treats source as live, then there cannot be data from future, only live data. So this time stamp is ignored OR it resets the internal matching counters.

Comment: It turns our its me: I was trying to be too clever: filling the inrush of samples as the stream started with silence -- of course then every sample after that is "late", and so the renderer runs flat out (which turns out to be around 44370).Its one of those cases where simply asking the question helped me to be more clear about what I was doing! Its a big problem for a one-man shop; nobody to vocalize problems with!